# How to enforce hive data types

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

Lets say I have a table "A" with the following schema:

```
field1 Decimal
field2 Decimal
field3 String
```

and table "B" with the following schema:

```
field1 String
field2 String
field3 String
```

Now, when I run the command `INSERT OVERWRITE table A SELECT * FROM B`,

Table A now contains all `NULL` values in column 1 and 2.

Is there a way to enforce the type so it would raise an exception on INSERT or when querying instead of showing `NULL` in the columns?

Answer (score 1):

If there is mismatch in datatypes hive inserts null data.You can typecast to required data type when you are selecting from table b. Select cast(columnname as datatypes) from b.